# Use forms in Angular material dialogue modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-material

I'm using angular material to manage my modal system and I would put forms into a modal and get the value after validation.

This is my code for a simple modal:

```
.factory('modalService', ['$mdDialog', function($mdDialog) {
    var modalService = {};
    modalService.alert = function(title, message, ev) {
      $mdDialog.show(
        $mdDialog.alert()
        .parent(angular.element(document.querySelector('#popupContainer')))
        .clickOutsideToClose(true)
        .title(title)
        .textContent(message)
        .ariaLabel('Alert Dialog Demo')
        .ok('OK')
        .targetEvent(ev)
      );
    };
    return modalService;
}])
```

Does anyone knows how to do ?

Answer (score 0):

MdDialogs can have templates and controllers attached. This code should get you started.

Also, look at the "custom dialog" demo [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog).

```js
$mdDialog.show({
  parent: parentEl,
  targetEvent: $event,
  template: '<md-dialog aria-label="List dialog">' +
    '  <md-dialog-content>' +
    '    <md-list>' +
    '      <md-list-item ng-repeat="item in items">' +
    '       <p>Number {{item}}</p>' +
    '      ' +
    '    </md-list-item></md-list>' +
    '  </md-dialog-content>' +
    '  <md-dialog-actions>' +
    '    <md-button ng-click="closeDialog()" class="md-primary">' +
    '      Close Dialog' +
    '    </md-button>' +
    '  </md-dialog-actions>' +
    '</md-dialog>',
  locals: {
    items: $scope.items
  },
  controller: DialogController
});

function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog, items) {
  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.closeDialog = function() {
    $mdDialog.hide();
  }
}
```

You can also use the templateUrl option and provide a template file if you don't want so much inline html, which is totally reasonable.